Redirect hanging in Next.js 14 when using Route Groups
I'm using Next.JS 14.2.15 and I have an actions.ts file located in app/(auth)/auth/actions.ts that calls redirect("/"); upon successful authentication.
I also have the main part of my application in another route group under app/(app)/page.tsx since they have separate layouts that don't extend one-another.
Before I moved into the route groups, the redirect worked as expected. However, once I moved into the route groups, the redirect now hangs. I've tried revalidatePath to no effect. If I redirect to auth/ it works just fine. But redirecting to / no longer works with route groups.
Any help is appreciated!

Using this GitHub issue, I resolved my route group x login server action x redirect() problem! I did the following to resolve it:

Added a layout.js in my root app directory (with html and body tag).

The docs are inconsistent sadly. For multiroot layout they suggest removing the top-level root layout.js but this leads to the problem we're experiencing. So advice: have a top level root layout.js


Make sure any nested layout.js files in route groups do not have html or body tags (docs) and their exported functional component are not also named RootLayout.

The next.js docs say: Only the root layout can contain html and body tags.



Hopefully you find this useful and it also fixes your redirect problem too!
